# Unable to obtain configuration from well-known/openid-configuration

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver3

I am using ASP.NET 5, In my solution I have Web API, Identity Server and Angular 2 project and I am authenticating Angular 2 client by using Identity Server, Angular 2 client consumes web api by passing token in http request and web api authenticate token and gives response, for this I have written a custom attribute which checks that user is authenticated or not

When I consume API I am getting following exception and Web API returns 500 internal server error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain
>   configuration from:
>   'http://xx.xx.xx.x:3926/.well-known/openid-configuration'. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from:
>   'http://xx.xx.xx.x:3926/.well-known/openid-configuration'. --->
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the
>   remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond xx.xx.xx.x:3926 at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)

Comment: Does your webapi have access to the identity server ? i.e. can you hit the URL /.well-know/openid-configuration from the webapi environment ?

Comment: Thanks for reply,
Yes

Comment: We have created a api method which is fetching configuration using "/.well-know/openid-configuration" URL.
It is giving us proper response if we try to hit this api method from browser directly as well as from other application too (using jquery ajax get call)

Comment: Is there a proxy configured on the system? When the application is deployed to IIS it won't have access to user configured proxies. You'll have to set it up on the OpenIdConnectOptions.BackchannelHttpHandler

Comment: Sounds like the server is either not running or you have disabled the metadata endpoint.

Comment: Also sounds like this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779542/a-task-was-canceled

Answer (score 21):

I used something like this, and it resolved my issue.

```
services.AddAuthentication(o => {
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })            
        .AddCookie(cfg => cfg.SlidingExpiration = true)
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Audience = "http://localhost:4200/";
            cfg.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/";
            cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            cfg.SaveToken = true;
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            cfg.Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration();  <-- Most IMP Part
        });
```

Comment: Working fine great answer

Comment: Could you please elaborate tokenValidationParameters? I did same thing but Authorize attribute is not working

Comment: @Saif not sure what I used at that time but you can look into this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/45723392/5816119

Comment: Your mention "Most IMP Part" was the most important to me. great THANK YOU.

Comment: Enjoy Suyon. :)

Comment: cfg.Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration();
resolved the issue.

Answer (score 17):

If identityserver and the access token validation middleware are hosted in the same application there is a race condition at startup.

The validation middleware tries to load the discovery document, which is not yet available.

In these scenarios, set the `DelayLoadMetadata` flag on the validation middleware to true.

If you disable the discovery endpoint altogether, you need to configure the issuer and key material on the validation options.

Comment: Perfect, this solved my issue. Thank you for the hasty responses. I now have my authorization and authentication embedded within my resource server.

Comment: This solved my issue as well. Should be marked as answer. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the Validation Middleware?

Comment: Can you explain where to set `DelayLoadMetadata` please? I can't seem to find it!

Comment: Can anyone please add the information where to find the configuration "DelayLoadMetadata", thanks

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779542/a-task-was-canceled

Answer (score 7):

The reason for this error was proxy and was able to resolve it by implementing the code below:

```
options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator,
                Proxy = new WebProxy(Configuration["System:Proxy"])
            };
```

If you are getting "unable to retrieve document from: '[pii is hidden]'" you need to add below to ConfigureServices:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
......
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
    }
```

I hope this help.

Comment: `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;` was indeed very helpful debugging a similar "Unable to retrieve document from.." error in my .Net 6.0 - API - JWT Bearer / Identity case.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was missing this:

```cs
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your appsettings.json tenant ID and make sure you didn't accidentally copy more than you need for the tenant ID.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, for us this issue was coming because our IT team had blocked the external calls from server, which means, when `OpenIdConnect` sdk tries fetch the said document, it will fail.

To overcome this without whitelisting external calls, we had to use a proxy in the `OpenIdConnect`. You might want to check `Backchannel` and `BackchannelHttpHandler` properties to use a proxy.

We had resolved these issues by using the proxy:

```
[TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.]
```

The second issue that was resolved was:

```
[IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/Mytenantid/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.]
...
...
...
```

Task cancellation was coming because of the request being timed-out while fetching from the URL ('https://login.microsoftonline.com/Mytenantid/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration') which was being blocked by our server.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error message for a couple of reasons.
One was solved with @leastprivilege answer.
Another was that my certs-files in my Identity Server project had been lost in Version control. So i just replaced the broken files with the originals and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding my SSO project fixed my problem. Nuget packages were restored as well during rebuilding the project. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anybody else.

I got this error after upgrading a project to .net core 2.0

the fix.

Change the name of the instance within appsettings.json
instead of

> "*AAD*Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"

use

> "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue testing on localhost with the dotnet run command. The call to /.well-known was performed on the wrong port. After adding a line to my startup class it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

managed to solve it by changing the application pool identity from "Applicationpoolidentity" to "Built-in Account". in built in account service account name and its password is given