# How to create a JWT web api and apply in web application core asp.net 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.0, jwt

Currently, I am developing web applications using asp.net core 2.0 and I need to apply JWT authentication web API into my web application. From my research, I found examples for asp.net core 1.0 but could not find for asp.net 2.0. What is the difference between JWT in Core 2.0 and Core 1.0? Is there any reference that I can refer to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JWT on .NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686477/jwt-on-net-core-2-0)

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52822924/5374333