# AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, ssl-certificate, azure-ad-b2c

I am performing a task to authenticate a Active-directory B2C instance in Azure from a local ToDo WebApp using a local WebAPI service.

I have created 2 Apps App1 and App2, apart from adding a B2C instance in a trial-version subscription of Azure. In local windows 10 OS, in Visual-Studio, I collected code for the ToDo Webapp and WebAPI Service as per a Microsoft-blog [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-api?tabs=csharpclient)

However, when I start the WebAPI service, and run the ToDoWebapp, the login after creating a user works fine, but after that, for any call to the service, I get the error-page with the message:
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot

> HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

How can one resolve this error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please check below points:

1. Installing the .NET Core SDK installs the ASP.NET Core HTTPS
   development certificate to the local user certificate store  as part
   of the first-run experience, but it is not trusted. To trust the
   certificate, perform the one-time step to run the dotnet dev-certs
   tool.
2. Check the certificates in the certificate store.Find
   localhost certificate with the ASP.NET Core HTTPS development
   certificate both under *Current User > Personal > Certificates* and
   *Current User > Trusted root certification authorities > Certificates*
3. Try to remove all found certificates by checking carefully from both Personal and Trusted root certification authorities.

> Note: Do not remove the IIS Express localhost certificate.

Try to run the following commands in .NET CLI and try again

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

> **Note:** Untrusted certificates should only be used during app development. Production apps should always use valid certificates.

**References:**

1. [Trust the ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate on Windows and
   macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos)
2. [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#windows---certificate-not-trusted-1)

Comment: I've tried these things. they didn't work

Comment: If you have x509 certificates, try checking them. I had some unused certificates there and removing those certificates worked for me. In ubuntu the path is ~/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/ca/

Comment: I am also  facing the same issue on different scenario. I am having Azure Function App developed using C# (.NET 8). And the code logic to do some API call using HttpClient. It is working fine in local. But after deploying in azure, it is throwing this error. Please how to solve this issue for my scenario.