# AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotTimeValid, UntrustedRoot

Tags: ssl-certificate, .net-6.0, webapi

I am struggling with following exception, which gets thrown in my Web API solution since today.
I cannot find anything in my certicate storage.

I tried to clean my dev certs and reinstall as decribed in this post:
[AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332944/authenticationexception-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-because-of-errors-in)

Extended exception details:

AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotTimeValid, UntrustedRoot

System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotTimeValid, UntrustedRoot

at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)

at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)

at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)

at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Any ideas what to check else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted an expired certificate which was located in "%AppData%\Roaming\ASP.NET\https" folder

After running clean and trust for the dev certs everything worked well

[see similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73403893/authenticationexception-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-because-of-errors-in)